# How to make this effect by css?

Tags: css

I need to make this effect, when picture merges with the background in same color, tried to search it in google but cant find solution, maybe with another div and relative position, interesting to  know name of this effect and how to use it

[image]

Comment: Do you mean making the image transparent, when the picture itself does not have alpha channel?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mask-image` css rule

```css
.image {
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0) 50%, transparent 100%);
}

body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
```